# INS-20802 Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed. during Oracle 19c installation

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

im new to programming and sql and I'm trying to install oracle 19c but at 71% i get 
`[INS-20802] Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed.`
in the details

```
[FATAL] Error during the execution of "C:\App\db_home\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql". 
Refering to "C:\App\IvanoOracleDB\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\dbmssml0.log"  for further details. 
Error at the process: C:\App\db_home\perl\bin\perl.exe for futher details,
see the log file "C:\App\IvanoOracleDB\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\orcl0.log".
```

Comment: So did you find anything interesting in ""C:\App\IvanoOracleDB\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\dbmssml0.log""  ?

Comment: Or C:\App\IvanoOracleDB\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\orcl0.log

Comment: I would suggest formatting the error message so that it is more readable than one long line.  Tried to propose an edit but need to change more that just adding a few line feeds.

Comment: I did the changes and added the logs

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your time, I did the edit you suggested.

"C:\App\IvanoOracleDB\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\dbmssml0.log" is empty

"C:\App\IvanoOracleDB\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\orcl0.log" :

```
[ 2020-03-26 15:05:50.945 CET ] [WARNING] [DBT-06208] The 'SYS' password entered does not conform to the recommended Oracle standards.
[ 2020-03-26 15:05:50.945 CET ] [WARNING] [DBT-06208] The 'SYSTEM' password entered does not conform to the recommended Oracle standards..
[ 2020-03-26 15:05:50.946 CET ] [WARNING] [DBT-06208] The 'PDADMIN' password entered does not conform to the recommended Oracle standards.
[ 2020-03-26 15:05:51.345 CET ] Prepare for DB operation
DBCA_PROGRESS : 8%
[ 2020-03-26 15:05:51.600 CET ] Copy of database files
DBCA_PROGRESS : 31%
[ 2020-03-26 15:07:48.799 CET ] Creating and starting the Oracle instance
DBCA_PROGRESS : 32%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 36%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 40%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 43%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 46%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 100%
[ 2020-03-26 15:15:08.930 CET ] [FATAL] Error during the execution of "C:\App\db_home\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql". Refering to "C:\App\IvanoOracleDB\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\dbmssml0.log" for further details. 
Error at the process: C:\App\db_home\perl\bin\perl.exe
    DBCA_PROGRESS : 31%
    DBCA_PROGRESS : 8%
    DBCA_PROGRESS : 0%
```